# Why would they special-case certain initializer lists instead of treating them all the same?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, list-initialization

Say I have a variable `auto x` that I want to initialize to `7` using brace initialization, simple:

```
auto x {7};
```

Except I learned that x is **NOT** an integer, but an initialization list itself. Why? Is there a specific reason why the committee would decide that `auto` should grab the initialization list in the case of a single auto value, or do they expect us to just realize these shouldn't be used together. **I cant seem to think of a possible reason i would want an initializer list to be stored into auto as opposed to the value**

Comment: Probably the real question is "Why would they special-case certain initializer lists instead of treating them all the same?".

Comment: @Mark B That feels like a much more in-depth explanation than my title. Feel free to edit for the rep, I won't steal it from you.

Comment: Ok. then what syntax do you suggest for an initialization list with one argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very practical answer is, "why should `int` be selected?"  Or `double`, or any UDT with an int single-argument constructor?  By declining to deduce a concrete type, the compiler preserves any possible application of the more general initializer list.

Comment: This is an unsatisfying answer. Why choose initializer_list? Why not tuple? The way they have done it, fails for `auto x {1, true };`. So the reason you give falsifies itself.

Answer (score 3):

> On the other hand, being able to deduce an `initializer_list<X>` for `T` is attractive to allow:
>
> ```
> auto x = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 };  
> f(x);   
> g(x);
> ```
>
> which was deemed desirable behavior since the very beginning of the EWG discussions about initializer lists.
>
> Rather than coming up with a clever deduction rule for a parameter type `T` matched with a {}-list (an option we pursued in earlier sketches and drafts of this paper), we now prefer to handle this with a special case for "auto" variable deduction when the initializer is a {}-list.  I.e., for the specific case of a variable declared with an "auto" type specifier and a {}-list initializer, the "auto" is deduced as for a function `f(initializer_list<T>)` instead of as for a `function f(T)`.

See chapter "Template argument deduction" in this PDF. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf

For the after-C++14, there is a paper that proposes to change these rules so that the one-element case deduces the type to the type of the initializer. The zero and multiple element case is proposed to become ill-formed. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html

Comment: Are you referring to 14.8.2 [temp.deduct]?

Comment: Update: It looks like the N3681 proposal (EWG Issue 73) has been rejected ("no consensus to change (concerns about breaking existing code)"): [C++ Standard Evolution Closed Issues List (Revision R04)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3813.html#73)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the reason is that so `auto` always interacts with initialization lists in the same way. In other words, the `auto` variable always becomes an initialization list rather than trying to deduce a different type in certain special cases like this one.